# What is the recommended interval for HPV vaccines such as Gardasil 9 for women and men up to age 45?

Tags: vaccination, virus, vaccine, hpv

> In October 2018, the US Food and Drug Administration announced it had expanded the approved age for the HPV vaccine up to age 45 for women and men. In June 2019, a key advisory committee for the US Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) recommended the vaccine for all men and women up to age 26. - https://www.mskcc.org/news/think-you-re-too-old-get-hpv-vaccine-prevent-cancer-maybe-not

It seems that this vaccine is usually given to pre-teens in a 2-dose series at 0, 6–12 months for  and to teens in a 3-dose series at 0, 1–2 months and 6 months. But for adults I can't find any recommended dose and interval. Will this also be a 3-dose series of similar interval as for teens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Center's for Disease Control and Prevention provides [recommendations](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/schedules/hcp/imz/adult.html) for all vaccines appropriate for adults.

[For HPV](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/schedules/hcp/imz/adult.html#note-hpv):

> Age 15 years **or older** at initial vaccination: 3-dose series at 0, 1–2 months, 6 months (minimum intervals: dose 1 to dose 2: 4 weeks / dose 2 to dose 3: 12 weeks / dose 1 to dose 3: 5 months; repeat dose if administered too soon)

In the United States, the Gardasil 9 formulation of HPV vaccine [is approved up to age 45](https://www.fda.gov/news-events/press-announcements/fda-approves-expanded-use-gardasil-9-include-individuals-27-through-45-years-old). The FDA notes in their press release that the trial data they used to expand the approval to age 45 used the standard 3 dose regimen.

Note, however, the vaccine is only "recommended" to age 26.

> HPV vaccination recommended for all persons through age 26 years

Individuals age 26 to 45 should discuss their individual situation with their healthcare provider to consider if the vaccine is right for them. Some insurance companies may not pay for vaccine doses in this age group because it is not recommended.

Comment: I suspect that the "recommendation" is only based on cost-effectiveness such as in this study. https://journals.plos.org/plosmedicine/article?id=10.1371/journal.pmed.1003534.